# Exporting a function from client side javascript, no the whole js file

Tags: javascript, import, export

I want to export a function that can be used in another js file. However, when I import the exported function from another js file, it imports the whole js file. How can I import only the function I want to export, instead of the whole js file.
Here are other codes in the js file:

```
function deleteCookie(cname) {
    const d = new Date();
    d.setDate(0);
    document.cookie = `${cname}= ; expires=${d.toUTCString ()}; path=/`; 
}
deleteCookie("authToken");
// document.querySelector("#my_form").reset();
let inputs =document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(let i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
    inputs[i].addEventListener("keyup",function(){
        HtmlSanitizer.SanitizeHtml(inputs[i].value);
    })  
}
let submitButton =document.querySelector("#submitButton");
let errorMessage=document.querySelectorAll(".sys-message");
let resetButton =document.querySelector("#Reset");
resetButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
    for(let i=0;i<errorMessage.length;i++){
        errorMessage[i].style.display="none";
    }
})
/**
 * Request ajax to check username's availability instantly and compare the username with regular expression,
 * disable the submit button if the username does not match with requirement.
 */
let usernameInput =document.querySelector("#txtUsername");
usernameInput.addEventListener("keyup",checkUsernameAvailability);

/**
 * Check if the passwords that user enter are the same and compatible with the regular expression.
 * Disable the submit button if the password does not match with requirement
 */
let password2Element = document.querySelector("#password2");
let password1Element = document.querySelector("#password1");
password2Element.addEventListener("keyup",test);
password1Element.addEventListener("keyup",test);
function test(){
    let passwordCheck =document.querySelector("#passwordConfirmation");
    let password1 =password1Element.value;
    let password2 =password2Element.value;
    const passwordPattern =/^(?=.{8,})(?![^a-zA-Z]+$)(?!\D+$)/;
    let usernameHintSpan =document.querySelector("#usernameAvailability");
    passwordCheck.style.display="inline";
    if((password1===password2)&&(passwordPattern.test(password1)==true)&&(passwordPattern.test(password2)==true)){
        passwordCheck.innerHTML= "&#10003;";
        passwordCheck.style.left="200px";
        passwordCheck.style.top=0;
        
        if(usernameHintSpan.innerHTML==="This username is taken, please choose another!"||usernameHintSpan.innerHTML==="Must be 4-16 characters (Abc 123 _ -)"){
            submitButton.disabled=true;
        }else{
            submitButton.disabled=false;
        }
    }else{
        submitButton.disabled=true;
        passwordCheck.style.left=0;
        passwordCheck.style.top="25px";
        if((passwordPattern.test(password1)==false)&&(passwordPattern.test(password2)==false)){
            passwordCheck.innerHTML="At least 8 characters, min 1 letter & 1 number";
        }else{
            passwordCheck.innerHTML="Passwords don't match, please re-enter";
        } 

    }   
};




// });

function passURL(url){
    return url;
}
```

Here are the codes of the exported function :

```
function checkUsernameAvailability(){
const url=passURL("app/newAccount")||passURL("/checkUser");
let usernameInput =document.querySelector("#txtUsername");
let usernameHintSpan =document.querySelector("#usernameAvailability");
usernameHintSpan.style.display="inline";
let username=usernameInput.value;
let usernamePattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{4,16}$/;
let request =new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange=function(){ 
    if((request.readyState==4)&&(request.status==200)){
        let str =request.responseText;
    //  console.log(str);
        if(str=="true"){
        usernameHintSpan.style.left=0;
        usernameHintSpan.style.top="25px";
            usernameHintSpan.innerHTML="This username is taken, please choose another!";
            submitButton.disabled=true;
        }else{
            if(usernamePattern.test(username)==true){
                usernameHintSpan.innerHTML= "&#10003;";
                usernameHintSpan.style.left="200px";
                usernameHintSpan.style.top=0;
                submitButton.disabled=false;
            }else{
            usernameHintSpan.style.left=0;
            usernameHintSpan.style.top="25px";
                usernameHintSpan.innerHTML="Must be 4-16 characters (Abc 123 _ -)";
                submitButton.disabled=true;
            }
            
        }
    }
};
request.open("GET",`${url}?username=`+username,true);
// request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send();
};



export { checkUsernameAvailability};
```

Here is the how I imported it:

```
import {checkUsernameAvailability} from "./newAccountPage.js";
```

Comment: what do you mean it imported the entire javascript file? you can also just put export in front of the function keyword

Comment: I tried. what I mean it's when loaded another js file, it import all the codes not just the function that i want to export

Comment: but you have only put `export { checkUsernameAvailability};`? What makes you think it has imported everything? Do you have code running in the global scope of that file?

Comment: Because when I load the page, in the console it shows:     newAccountPage.js:8 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'reset')
    at newAccountPage.js:8
(anonymous) @ newAccountPage.js:8 ...   It loads other codes as well

Comment: so that must be in the global scope then. Read through [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) and see if that helps you better understand how modules are loaded in js. The problem you are having doesnt seem to have anything to do with the code you have shown here

Comment: I don't quite understand?

Comment: read the link. You have code running in the global scope of that file, this will run at compile time (when you import it) unless it is wrapped in a function of its own.

Comment: Ok, I do have lots of variables running globally, maybe that's why.Thank you